# Silverlight XAML Binding ElementName

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding

I have the following XAML:

```
            <sdk:Label Content="{Binding RefreshTextToggle, Converter={StaticResource enumToText}, ConverterParameter=ItemsOfInterest,FallbackValue='Please select items of interest to you'}" 
                       Style="{StaticResource StandardLabel}"
                       Height="{Binding ElementName=ItemsOfInterest,Path=Height}"/>

            <ListBox Name="ItemsOfInterest" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsOfInterest}" 
                     Margin="5"
                     MinHeight="25"
                     Width="250"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left">
```

The height of the ItemsOfInterest is dynamic pending on how many elements are in it.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong with the height binding? It isn't even close to the same size as the ItemsOfInterst.

Comment: I think you would be better off to simply use a grid or stackpanel to coordinate the size relationship between these two elements.

Comment: I wish I could, they are actually in two different Grids Columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should bind to [ActualHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), which specifies the height it was arranged at. The Height property allows you to set a fixed height, but doesn't tell you exactly how tall it is when arranged.

---

EDIT:

Actually, this is a [known bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522231/silverlight-grid-stackpanel-canvas-actualheight-and-acutalwidth-is-0) with Silverlight.

You would have to use the SizeChanged event like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication3.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Content="Add Item" Click="Button_Click" />

        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" SizeChanged="listBox1_SizeChanged" />
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

With a code-behind of:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SilverlightApplication3 {
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl {
        public MainPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int counter;

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            this.counter++;
            this.listBox1.Items.Add(counter.ToString());
        }

        private void listBox1_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
            this.listBox2.Height = this.listBox1.ActualHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

You could probably wrap this up into a nice attached behavior also.

---

EDIT:
Here is such a behavior:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication3.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication3"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Content="Add Item" Click="Button_Click" />

        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" local:SizeSynchronizationBehavior.HeightElement="{Binding ElementName=listBox1}" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

With a code-behind of:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SilverlightApplication3 {
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl {
        public MainPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int counter;

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            this.counter++;
            this.listBox1.Items.Add(counter.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static class SizeSynchronizationBehavior {

        #region Dependency Properties

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // HeightElement
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the <c>HeightElement</c> attached dependency property.  This field is read-only.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The identifier for the <c>HeightElement</c> attached dependency property.</value>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeightElementProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HeightElement",
            typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(SizeSynchronizationBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnHeightElementPropertyValueChanged));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value of the <see cref="HeightElementProperty"/> attached property for the specified <see cref="FrameworkElement"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object to which the attached property is retrieved.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The value of the <see cref="HeightElementProperty"/> attached property for the the specified <see cref="FrameworkElement"/>.
        /// </returns>
        public static FrameworkElement GetHeightElement(FrameworkElement obj) {
            if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
            return (FrameworkElement)obj.GetValue(HeightElementProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the value of the <see cref="HeightElementProperty"/> attached property to the specified <see cref="FrameworkElement"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object to which the attached property is written.</param>
        /// <param name="value">
        /// The new value of the <see cref="HeightElementProperty"/> attached property to the specified <see cref="FrameworkElement"/>.
        /// </param>
        public static void SetHeightElement(FrameworkElement obj, FrameworkElement value) {
            if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
            obj.SetValue(HeightElementProperty, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when <see cref="HeightElementProperty"/> is changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">The dependency object that was changed.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private static void OnHeightElementPropertyValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            FrameworkElement element = d as FrameworkElement;
            if (element == null)
                return;

            SizeChangedEventHandler heightSizeChangedEventHandler = GetSizeChangedEventHandler(element);
            if (heightSizeChangedEventHandler == null) {
                heightSizeChangedEventHandler = (sender, eventArgs) => {
                    FrameworkElement he = GetHeightElement(element);
                    if (he != null)
                        element.Height = he.ActualHeight;
                };
                SetSizeChangedEventHandler(element, heightSizeChangedEventHandler);
            }

            FrameworkElement heightElement = e.OldValue as FrameworkElement;
            if (heightElement != null)
                heightElement.SizeChanged += heightSizeChangedEventHandler;

            heightElement = e.NewValue as FrameworkElement;
            if (heightElement != null)
                heightElement.SizeChanged += heightSizeChangedEventHandler;

        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // SizeChangedEventHandler
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the <c>SizeChangedEventHandler</c> attached dependency property.  This field is read-only.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The identifier for the <c>SizeChangedEventHandler</c> attached dependency property.</value>
        private static readonly DependencyProperty SizeChangedEventHandlerProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SizeChangedEventHandler",
            typeof(SizeChangedEventHandler), typeof(SizeSynchronizationBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value of the <see cref="SizeChangedEventHandlerProperty"/> attached property for the specified <see cref="FrameworkElement"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object to which the attached property is retrieved.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The value of the <see cref="SizeChangedEventHandlerProperty"/> attached property for the the specified <see cref="FrameworkElement"/>.
        /// </returns>
        private static SizeChangedEventHandler GetSizeChangedEventHandler(FrameworkElement obj) {
            if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
            return (SizeChangedEventHandler)obj.GetValue(SizeChangedEventHandlerProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the value of the <see cref="SizeChangedEventHandlerProperty"/> attached property to the specified <see cref="FrameworkElement"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object to which the attached property is written.</param>
        /// <param name="value">
        /// The new value of the <see cref="SizeChangedEventHandlerProperty"/> attached property to the specified <see cref="FrameworkElement"/>.
        /// </param>
        private static void SetSizeChangedEventHandler(FrameworkElement obj, SizeChangedEventHandler value) {
            if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
            obj.SetValue(SizeChangedEventHandlerProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion // Dependency Properties
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not working in my POC.  Also, ActualHeight returns the vertical height of the screen in full mode according to MS docs.

Comment: @Nissan - Are you looking at the ListBox.ActualHeight?

Comment: Yes.  If you bind to this the height does not change for the Auto-height listbox.

Comment: @Nissan - You're right, looks like it works in WPF but not Silverlight. Updated with only known work around of using SizeChanged.

Comment: Looks great.  Good work everyone.  Nice to learn about these corner cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort put into this. It's a great help!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple project which replicates the problem you are experiencing:

1. Added a listbox and button
2. Hooked the button to the height of the listbox
3. Set the listbox height to "Auto"
4. Created another button which adds a random amount of items to the Listbox

On run, the listbox grows, but the associated button does not.  I am now working to determine why this fails.

**UPDATE**

Okay, the reason why this does not work is that Auto does not return any actual value that can be used to determine the height of the listbox by this binding.  I tried every other approach to solve this without success. It will be interesting to see the resolution of this problem while just relying on binding.

Comment: The button doesn't grow because it's Height will be Auto (the default value) just like the ListBox. So they will only take up as much vertical space as needed to show their content.

Comment: @CodeNaked Agree.  But even pointing to other Path's on Listbox such as ActualHeight, ItemsPanel.VisualTree.Height, etc. all results in the same end result.