# ActualHeight binding does not update

Tags: silverlight, binding, silverlight-4.0, actualheight

I am trying to set up a binding to the `ActualHeight` of a `FrameworkElement`. It only seems to update once, but never updates after that. I tested this in a simple silverlight application with this markup, and it doesn't update when the browser window is resized. If I hook the `LayoutUpdated`, you can see that the `ActualHeight` is changing, but it is not updating the binding.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" />
</Grid>
```

Shouldn't I be able to bind to `ActualHeight`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Silverlight. See [this post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522231/silverlight-grid-stackpanel-canvas-actualheight-and-acutalwidth-is-0) for more information. You'd need to use a solution like I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585371/silverlight-xaml-binding-elementname/5585626#5585626).